# Tech stack selection for DMP systems

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-flink, druid, kylin

Our DMP system has such a demand：
1. Audience Export: Audience based on tag need to export new demographic results to Redis or files every day, to DSP. Because the tag data is refreshed every day.We have 600 million users.When we have tens of thousands of people, what kind of technology stack should we choose to quickly calculate and export?
2. Event Analysis： We also need to create Audience based on real-time events.We need to add qualified people to the Audience.At the same time, people who do not meet the requirements need to be removed as time goes by.
There is a suitable technical stack recommendation to meet one or both.

Thank you.

Comment: Voted to close as it is asking for software recommendations. Which is outside the scope of this site unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

We work extensively with audience data from DMPs and generally manage many petabytes of data and hundreds of audiences.

I would recommend going with Apache Spark for processing because of:

1. The flexibility of the programming model.
2. The prevalence of batch processing in DMP workflows.
3. High performance for normal audience sizes (they fit in RAM).
4. Widest set of integrations, including to ML capabilities, which are becoming more important for DMPs.

Storage is a more complicated issue:

- Object storage (S3) is the easiest but not the best performing.
- HDFS-style storage is faster in many cases but has higher cost.
- As audiences are sets, depending on performance needs for audience updates, you may also consider a key-value store, e.g., Cassandra.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The Cloudera Data Platform contains Spark, Hbase (can serve as key value store), and since recently also Hdfs backed by S3. - - Disclaimer: I am an employee of Cloudera (but felt the push is warranted given the question)